# SQL Pivot Dynamic Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that generates results for learners on a specific course showing whether or not they have completed a module. Learners can take different modules from each other.

```
SELECT LearnerID, 
       UnitID, 
       CASE WHEN (SUM(Total - [Total Achieved])) = 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Completed 
FROM  dbo.LMS_Achieved_Standards_Report 
GROUP BY CourseID, LearnerID, UnitID
```

The results look like this

```
LearnerID  UnitID  Completed
15      15        Yes
15      28        No
28      28        Yes
116     150       Yes
79      12        No
69      34        Yes
69      15        No
```

I need it to look like this:

```
LearnerID     Unit 15  Unit 28  Unit 150  Unit 12  Unit 34
15              Yes      No
28                       Yes
116                               Yes
79                                          Yes
69              No                                   Yes
```

The other factor as already stated is that they can all take different units so I can't create a PIVOT with set column headings.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried searching for dynamic pivot here on SO?

Comment: I have but I just can't figure out how to write the query

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
    select * into #tbl from (select 'cust1' as key1,    'Red'as Type
union select 'cust1' as key1,   'Blue'as Type
union select 'cust1' as key1,   'Yellow'as Type
union select 'cust2' as key1,   'Red'as Type
union select 'cust2' as key1,   'Blue'as Type
union select 'cust2' as key1,   'Green'as Type) as dd

declare @strsql as nvarchar(max)
declare @columns as nvarchar(max)

set @columns = (select stuff((select distinct ',['+Type+']' from #tbl FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''))
set @strsql =  'select key1,'+@columns + 'from (select * from #tbl) as p pivot (count(p.Type) For p.Type in ('+@columns+'))as pivottable'
--set @strsql = 'select 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @strsql
```